# Api for MS Office document comparation

Tags: .net, compare, ms-office, dms

I'm writing (possibly) a small document management system. Technology of choice is ASP MVC. I'm looking for api/framework to compare MS Office documents (Word, Excel). I have found this:

[groupdocs](http://groupdocs.com/) - it's exactly what I was looking for but prices are killing me.

Other options I have founds are stand alone applications, one of which is not perfect but could do the job.
[comparesuite](http://www.comparesuite.com/)
- it has silent command line mode that can generate HTML diff report.

Answer (score 0):

You can check for www.docunate.com

Recently developed DMS which supports a lot of features and formats

Drop in a mail at anshul.taneja12@gmail.com